# how to use last insert id when redirect same form page in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I just try to prevent re submission problem when refresh form page. so I use session flashdata() method and redirect same form page. but I want also display recent inputed data on form VIEW page. then I am try `$this->db->insert_id()` on my form VIEW page . but it always show 0. **how can I solve it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you redirect the user after the successful form submission then add the parameter in the url just a exapmle with dummy code to make an idea for you

```
$insertedid=$this->my_model->add_info();

 //your add_info() should return the inserted id
redirect("/myformcontroller/myformpage/".$this->db->insert_id());// add id in redirect url
```

on your `myformcontroller` controller's `myformpage` function

```
 function myformpage() {
$insertedid=$this->url->segment(3);
if(!empty($insertedid)){
 //get new added information and pass it to view
} 
// your other code
}
```

hope it makes sense